# WPF DataGrid Footer Row

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is there any **built-in** way to add a footer row into the WPF DataGrid in .NET 4?  From what I'm seeing the answer appears to be no, but I can't imagine something so basic could have been left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is no **built-in** way to add a footer.The best possible custom implementation I found is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/31/wpf-datagrid-frozen-row-sample.aspx)

Comment: I saw that, thank you.  Looks like I'll be shopping for third party toolkits tomorrow at work :'(

Comment: I strongly believe that Microsoft datagrid is havinf far too many limitations and is having lot of bugs.So third party controls is the only way for now.